# Spring Security and Token Auth for API

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-boot

I've been scouring the web looking at a lot of different ways to implement token based authentication using Spring & Spring Security (SS). I'm not really wanting to go the full on Oauth route so I've been trying to do something and keep things pretty simple.

What I want is to pass a username/password to SS's built in mechanism and on success, generate a token that I pass back to the user. The user then makes all future requests with the token in a custom header. The token will expire after som length of time. I am aware this is kind of what Oauth does but again, don't want to use it.

So I've got something kind of working. I can login with username/password and get the token back. I can then make requests with the token successfully. What isn't working are authorities. Here's what I'm doing...

- Custom Auth Failure Handler that simply returns `HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED`
- Custom Success Handler that simply returns `HttpServletResponse.SC_OK` and the token
- Custom Auth Entry Point that just response with `HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED`

Now, I also have a custom UserDetails and UserDetailsService.

```
public class MyUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private User user; // this is my own User object
    private List<GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public MyUserDetails(User user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.user = user;
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public void setAuthorities(List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }
}

@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public MyUserDetailsService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        // for now, just add something
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        return new MyUserDetails(user, authorities);
    }
}
```

In order to look in the header for the token and tell spring all is well, I created a AuthTokenFilter...

```
public class AuthTokenFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String authToken = httpRequest.getHeader("X-TOKEN-AUTH");
        String username = null;
        if (authToken != null) {
            username = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey("1234")
                    .parseClaimsJws(authToken)
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();


        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            // TODO: validate token
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
            authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpRequest));
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }
}
```

And this is how I've configured web security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private RestAuthEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private AuthSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private AuthFailureHandler authFailureHandler;


    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception {
        return super.userDetailsServiceBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(new ShaPasswordEncoder());

        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        AuthTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter = new AuthTokenFilter();
        authenticationTokenFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        return authenticationTokenFilter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1);

        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }


}
```

Everything seems to work accept SS isn't limiting access at all. If the token is there SS just lets everything pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, after much trial and error it was as simple as adding the following to my `SpringSecurityConfig`

`@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)`

Kind of surprised that I didn't run into this sooner. Not sure if this is something somewhat new or what.